# How to generate bitstream (.bin) file using Synplify

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am using Synplify version 9.6.2

I would like to generate a .bin file to load onto the FPGA. The output from Synplify is a .edn or.edf netlist.

Anyone know what is the process for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the EDIF netlist and feed it through Xilinx's tools (ISE) to get the EDF converted to a placed-and-routed design and then to  a bitstream in .bin format.